# Unable to resolve activity for: Intent

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am having a problem in running Android unit test. I got this error when I tried to run a simple test.

Here's the log:

> Blockquote
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.wsandroid.Activities/.SplashActivity }
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:371)
>   at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:120)
>   at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:98)
>   at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:87)
>   at com.wsandroid.test.activity.TestEULA.setUp(TestEULA.java:15)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
>   at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)

This error occurs for Android less than 2.2. It works fine for Android 2.2 emulator. Yet Android 2.2 emulator has a bug of sending a key twice even though we only press it one. Application to be tested runs on Android 2.2 platform.

Appreciate if anyone of you can help me.

Dzung.

Answer (score 15):

This can also be cause by a missing

Make sure you have a corresponding entry in your manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"  ...
```

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem with a simple test project for an app that was just a splash screen.  I found that I had implemented the constructor wrong.  My initial implementation of the constructor was this...

```
public SplashScreenTest(){
    super("com.mycomp.myapp.SplashScreen", SplashScreen.class);
}
```

After some beating my head against the wall, I somehow decided to remove the SplashScreen from the pkg argument of super().  My successful implementation is now like this...

```
public SplashScreenTest() {
    super("com.mycomp.myapp", SplashScreen.class);
}
```

I hope that this helps you or others solve the problem.

Comment: Would someone please explain to me why "It works fine for Android 2.2 emulator"?

Comment: now it's depreciated anyway and should super(SplashScreen.class); be used instead.

Answer (score 7):

Try to check your Manifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.tablet.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <!-- This line below! -->
    <instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.tablet.tablet"
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" /> 
</manifest>
```

You need to check the following line:

```
<instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.tablet.tablet"
android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

So the targetPackage must be the same as in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I had specific similar problem while using the **AndroidAnnotations** lib.

Later, I found out it was due to forgetting to use the generated class (`MyActivity_` instead of `MyActivity`).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that TestFragmentActivity, meaning the Activity used in our test

```
extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TestFragmentActivity>
```

must be available in the package defined in Manifest.xml as targetPackage:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="de.my.androidhd" />
```

My solution was to move TestFragmentActivity into tested application package.

Answer (score -1):

For the keys being sent twice issue, are you sure you're not now getting both the Down and Up actions?  I had this issue when using Robotium, and generated this to make things easier:

```
import android.view.KeyCharacterMap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

        public static void type(Solo robot, EditText edit, String text) {
            int index = 0;
            //Find the index of this control, as Robotium doesn't seem to like R.id
            for (int i = 0; i < robot.getCurrentEditTexts().size(); i++) {
                if (robot.getCurrentEditTexts().get(i).getId() == edit.getId()) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            robot.clickOnEditText(index);

            KeyCharacterMap map = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);
            KeyEvent[] events = map.getEvents(text.toCharArray());

            for (int event = 0; event < events.length; event++) {
                if (events[event].getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    robot.sendKey(events[event].getKeyCode());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had two activities with same name in different packages. Issue was about importing from the wrong package. I spend much time on it maybe it will save someone some time.

Comment: Please write this as comment and not as an answer, because it doesn't adress the problem!