# Android Is Remembering My Old Package Name?

Tags: java, android, junit

When I first created my test project I told it that my package was com.example.test. Now, i've renamed the source package to com.imcool.android, and I also updated the package in my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.imcool.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

After a full clean, Android asks me if I want to update my launch configurations, I click yes. I try and run an android unit test and I get this error:

```
Test run failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.imcool.android/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
```

If I change the package in my manifest back to com.example.test it works, even though my actual source package name is still com.imcool.android.

Whats the deal?

Comment: Are you sure that the new package is being deployed at your device/emulator?

Comment: Note that you must use a different package name (`<manifest package="..."` in AndroidManifest.xml) for test project, the actual source package name does not matter as long as you refer your components using the correct package prefix in AndroidManifest.xml. Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854936/unable-to-resolve-activity-for-intent-when-instrumentation-testing-android-acti) for more details.

Comment: I'm really glad you posted that yorkw, that was another issue I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not android that has asked you . it's eclipse . :)

anyway, just go to the run-configuarations and delete all of the items that aren't needed anymore , and do the run again . this way it will forget about the previous configuration and will use only those that you ask of it.