# Android maven instrumentation tests failing

Tags: android, instrumentation

I have been recently trying my hand at using Android Instrumentation tests. So the main application has the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>One Stop Spot</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The pm.xml file has the following structure

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        onestopspot
        parent
        1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    
    com.onestopspot
    instrumentation
    apk
    One Stop Shop- Instrumentation Test

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
        <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>apk</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
        <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>emma</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>emma</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma</artifactId>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <version>2.1.5320</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>project.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <test>
                            <coverage>true</coverage>
                            <createReport>true</createReport>
                        </test>
                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <!-- -->
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pull-coverage</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>pull</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <pullSource>/data/data/com.onestopspot.api/files/coverage.ec</pullSource>
                                <pullDestination>${tested.project.dir}/target/emma/coverage.ec</pullDestination>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>emma4it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <metadatas>${tested.project.dir}/target/emma/coverage.em,${tested.project.dir}/src/
                        </metadatas>
                        <instrumentations>${tested.project.dir}/target/emma/coverage.ec</instrumentations>
                        <reportDirectory>${tested.project.dir}/target/emma/</reportDirectory>
                        <baseDirectory>{tested.project.dir}/target/</baseDirectory>
                        <formats>xml,html</formats>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>

                <test>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <!--<instrumentationPackage>packageName</instrumentationPackage> -->
                    <!--<instrumentationRunner>className</instrumentationRunner> -->
                    <!--<debug>true|false</debug> -->
                    <!--<coverage>true|false</coverage> -->
                    <!--<logonly>true|false</logonly> avd -->
                    <!--<testsize>small|medium|large</testsize> -->
                    <testSize>small</testSize>
                    <createReport>true</createReport>
                    <!--<classes> -->
                    <!--<class>your.package.name.YourTestClass</class> -->
                    <!--</classes> -->
                    <!--<packages> -->
                    <!--<package>your.package.name</package> -->
                    <!--</packages> -->
                </test>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now in my main project, under com.onestopspot.api i have my android application class. In the onCreate function i have a simple log.d message that tell me that application class in been created. Now in my test project, i have a com.onestopspot.api i have the following class

```
package com.onestopspot.api;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner;
import android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder;

public class AllTests extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(AllTests.class)
                .includeAllPackagesUnderHere()
                .build();
    }
}
```

now when i say mvn clean install i get the following exception

```
[INFO] SH28HTV04654_HTC_HTCOneV :       java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1677)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:371)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.onestopspot.api.MyApplication
at com.onestopspot.api.ApplicationTests.<init>(ApplicationTests.java:38)
... 18 more
```

what am i doing wrong ? I have been at this for two days. My project looks nearly identicle to that found here [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AutomateAndroidTestProject), but that works this does not ? I could send my code if any one could help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): failed: testSuiteConstructionFailed(android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): ----- begin exception -----
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1677)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:371)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4456)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **com.onestopspot.api.MyApplication**
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     at com.onestopspot.api.APITest.<init>(APITest.java:38)
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928):     ... 18 more
03-16 19:05:11.068: I/TestRunner(9928): ----- end exception -----
03-16 19:05:11.078: I/TestRunner(9928): finished: testSuiteConstructionFailed(android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests)
03-16 19:05:11.088: I/ActivityManager(1656): Force stopping package com.onestopspot.api uid=10161
```

The com.onestopspot.api.MyApplication is my application class in the main project. My instrumentation project seems not to be able to find it ?

Comment: Looking at logcat, does it provide any additional information?

Comment: no. Just the error that i have provided. Could i send you the sample project. its very small, just 2 classes ?

Comment: I don't have any of the setup or gear here to run your project, so sending it would unfortunatly not do much good. Have you tried reducing your project to the bare minimum?

Comment: it is the bare minimum. One application class, one activity in the main project. and one application instrumentation class. I have edited  the logcat exception in my question.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854936/unable-to-resolve-activity-for-intent-when-instrumentation-testing-android-acti/8857120#8857120) helps.

Comment: Thanks, there were alot of things i was doing wrong. The above solved the last error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>apk</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>apk</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>api_library</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. It turned out that my app and my test project had the same package name (in the manifest file). Adb uninstalls and installs the apk's by there package name.
This set of instructions was executed by adb just before executing the tests:

- Uninstall the app
- Install the app
- Uninstall the tests (if they have the same package name as the app, this will uninstall your app!!)
- Install the tests
- Run the tests

Therefore in my project everything was fixed when I renamed the package of my instrumentation tests.